# Swift JSON parsing error with PHP/mySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift, post

I am currently trying to parse JSON objects returned from a PHP/mySQL script that utilizes POST method variables in the PHP script.

Half the time I run the viewcontroller, it errors out (THREAD 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION) and doesn't return JSON, but half the time it works. I'm really unsure why it's doing this. Sometimes the error occurs when it's parsing "grabID.php" and sometimes the error occurs when it's parsing "loadSongsIntoParty.php"

Here is my viewDidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    partyNameLabel.text = recievedPartyName
    PINLabel.text = recievedPIN

    println(self.recievedPIN)
    println(self.recievedHost)
    println(self.recievedGenre)

    let idData = "PIN=\(self.recievedPIN)&host=\(self.recievedHost)&genre=\(self.recievedGenre)"

    let idURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://myserverURL/grabID.php")!
    var idPostData:NSData = idData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    var idRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:idURL)
    idRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    idRequest.HTTPBody = idPostData

    var IDresponseError: NSError?
    var IDresponse: NSURLResponse?

    var IDurlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(idRequest, returningResponse: &IDresponse, error: &IDresponseError)

    var IDs: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(IDurlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)

    println(IDs)


    if let IDjson = IDs as? Array<AnyObject> {

        for index in 0...IDjson.count-1 { //where error occurs sometimes

            let songID : AnyObject? = IDjson[index]

            let songIDs = songID! as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            let ID : AnyObject! = songIDs["ID"]

            self.partyID.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            self.partyID.append(ID as String)


        }


    }

    println(self.partyID[0])

    IDLabel.text = self.partyID[0]

    let queryID = self.partyID[0]
    let queryGenre = self.recievedGenre

    let loadIntoVotes = "queryID=\(queryID)&queryGenre=\(queryGenre)"

    let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://myserverURL/~team11/loadSongs.php")!
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.HTTPBody = loadIntoVotes.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in

    }


   // mySQL json parsing script




    let loadSongsID = self.partyID[0]


    let bodyData = "partyID=\(loadSongsID)" //To get them in php: $_POST['name']


    let songURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://myserverurl/loadSongsIntoParty.php")!
    var postData:NSData = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    var songsRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:songURL)
    songsRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    songsRequest.HTTPBody = postData

    var responseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(songsRequest, returningResponse: &response, error: &responseError)

    var allSongs: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)


    if let songsJson = allSongs as? Array<AnyObject> {

        println(songsJson)


        for index in 0...songsJson.count-1 { //where error occurs sometimes

            let indivSong : AnyObject? = songsJson[index]

            let collection = indivSong! as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            let track : AnyObject! = collection["track"]
            let artist : AnyObject! = collection["artist"]
            let trackURI : AnyObject! = collection["trackURI"]
            let vote: AnyObject! = collection["vcount"]

            self.tracks.append(track as String)
            self.names.append(artist as String)
            self.tracksURI.append(trackURI as String)
            self.votes.append(vote as String)

        }


    }
```

Here is my grabID php script:

```
 <?php

 // Create connection                                                            
 $con=mysqli_connect("#####", "#####", "#####", "#####");


 // Check connection                                                             
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 // Change character set to utf8                                                 
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

 $partyPIN = $_POST['PIN'];
 $host = $_POST['host'];
 $genre = $_POST['genre'];


 $sql = "SELECT ID from party where PIN = '$partyPIN' and host = '$host' and  genre = '$genre'";

 // Check to see if there are results                                            
 if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))

 {

 // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one to hold date          

 $resultArray = array();
 $tempArray = array();

 // loop through each row in the result set                                      
 while($row = $result->fetch_object())
 {
 //Add each row into our results array                                           
 $tempArray = $row;

array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}

 // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results                     
 echo json_encode($resultArray);
 }


 mysqli_close($con)

?>
```

Here is my loadSongsIntoParty PHP script:

```
 <?php

 // Create connection                                                            
 $con=mysqli_connect("#####", "#####", "######", "######");


 // Check connection                                                             
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 // Change character set to utf8                                                 
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

 $ID = $_POST['partyID'];

 $sql = "select track, artist, trackURI, vcount from votes where PID = '$ID'";

 // Check to see if there are results                                            
 if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))

 {

 // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one to hold date          

 $resultArray = array();
 $tempArray = array();

 // loop through each row in the result set                                      
 while($row = $result->fetch_object())
 {
 //Add each row into our results array                                           
 $tempArray = $row;

  array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
 }

 // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results                     
 echo json_encode($resultArray);
 }


 mysqli_close($con)

 ?>
```

Comment: You need to read up on SQL injection vulnerabilities, as you have them.  Hard to say what is going on without further debugging information from you.  When failures have occurred, have you looked at PHP logs to determine what is going wrong?  What sort of debugging have you done?

Comment: @MikeBrant I know I do, this is just for a school project so security is taking a backseat to functionality (for the moment). I have limited programming knowledge. I have my php stored on a university server, so how can I view the PHP error logs?

Comment: Are you sure the "IDjson" array always has at least one element? Since you iterate with "IDjson.count-1", it could be the source of the error.